# Visual SVN Server Post-commit Hook Fails

Tags: svn, hook, visualsvn-server

I want to checkout the most recent files of the repository to a folder on the local hard drive of the server whenever a commit happens.

My post-commit hook right now is:

```
svn checkout https://xyz.mysite.com:7405/svn/ProjectName/ C:\my-temp --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --username myusername --password mypassword
```

The .CMD file that VisualSVN Server created runs great inside Windows's Command Prompt and does what I need it to do. But when it comes to running it when a commit happens, an error gets returned to the SVN client and nothing appear in the destination folder.

The error message says `Access to /svn/ProjectName forbidden` even though the credentials work perfectly in Commpand Prompt.

Please let me know what I need to do to the script for the hook to run. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have [Integrated Windows Authentication](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/windows-auth/) (i.e. Active Directory Single Sign-On) enabled on the server? In such case, `--username` and `--password` arguments won't work because `svn.exe`, when called from the hook script, will authenticate under the user account that runs VisualSVN Server HTTP service.

There are several ways to get rid of the authentication problem:

- If you run the service under Network Service (HTTP service runs under this account by default), provide the AD **computer** account with Read permissions to `/svn/ProjectName/`. Network Service account works under computer account's credentials on the network.
- Run `svn checkout` against `file://` URL. This way the client access the repository directly on the filesystem and no special authentication is required. The URL should look like `file:///C:\Repositories\MyProject`.

Comment: Yep. I figured it out a while ago and it was because "NETWORK SERVICE" didn't have access to the SVN repo. Thanks!